# WCF unable to find netTcpBinding

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding, endpoint, webhttpbinding

I am trying to create a WCF service that is accessible through both webHttpBinding and netTcpBinding. I have been successful in getting the webHttpBinding to be accessible through a Java client and now I'm working on trying to get the netTcpBinding working.

I have set up the configuration like this;

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="httpBehavior">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  <services>
    <service name="MR_Jukebox_Service.JukeboxService">
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MR_Jukebox_Service/"/>
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8523/Design_Time_Addresses/MR_Jukebox_Service/net/"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint address=""
                behaviorConfiguration="httpBehavior"
                binding="webHttpBinding"
                contract="MR_Jukebox_Service.IJukeboxService" />
      <endpoint address="mex"
                binding="mexHttpBinding"
                contract="MR_Jukebox_Service.IJukeboxService" />
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8523/Design_Time_Addresses/MR_Jukebox_Service/net"
                binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration=""
                contract="MR_Jukebox_Service.IJukeboxService" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

In the same solution, I have a test application that I wish to connect to the netTcpBinding, I've right clicked on "Service References" and chosen "Add Service Reference...".
When I click on "Discover" it finds the service although says;

> There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MR_Jukebox_Service'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MR_Jukebox_Service'.
>   There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MR_Jukebox_Service that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>   The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

But I am also unable to see the netTcpBinding in order for me to create a service reference to it.

I was wondering whether anyone can see what I am doing wrong as its probably something rather simple, but due to my lack of experience with WCF haven't noticed.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Also: your MEX endpoint(s) **MUST** use the `IMetadataExchange`  contract - **not** your own service contract!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your mex endpoint to this:

```
<endpoint address="mex"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

You were using your service's contract for the mex endpoint, which I don't believe will work.

You can set up a similar one for the NetTcpBinding:

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8523/Design_Time_Addresses/MR_Jukebox_Service/net/mex"
          binding="mexTcpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Comment: Thank you, I got thrown by the second part though, but eventually figured it was mexTcpBinding not mexNetTcpBinding.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Sorry for the typo - I'll edit my answer so it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

> I have been successful in getting the webHttpBinding to be accessible through a Java client and now I'm working on trying to get the netTcpBinding working.

Are you trying to get the netTcpBinding to work with a java client ? Because, netTcpBinding **only** works with a .net client.

NetTcpBinding is not designed for interop, it's designed for performance when both the server and client are .net

Comment: Ah yes re-reading that it does sound like I am trying to do that doesn't it. I'm developing the WCF service to be consumable by both .NET applications (using netTcpBinding) and applications developed in other programming languages (using webHttpBinding). Thank you confirming that though :)